# Orchard CMS and javascript: Number.parseInvariant

Tags: javascript, orchardcms

I can't get certain jscript functions in Orchard. At this moment I am struggling with `Number.parseInvariant` function. This works fine when using a standard ASP.Net mvc3 web application, but when porting it into Orchard this function cannot be used. I think the same goes also for Sys object. My two pennies is that in ASP.net MVC another implementation of the scripting libraries is used then in Orchard.

Anyone knows how I can bypass this. Or maybe some alternatives to this specific function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number.parseInvariant and sys are extensions brought by Microsoft Ajax, it's not standard JavaScript. Microsoft Ajax is an obsolete library that you shouldn't be using. Please use more standard ways to do the same thing, such as parseInt.

Answer (score -2):

I have added Microsoft.Ajax.js to the project and referenced it. I dont know if this is the best way. At least it works for me now.

Comment: Hi Bertrand. I like your answer better. I will try to replace any MicrosoftAjax functions with more standard solutions.